# How to customize json-server error handling

Tags: javascript, json-server

I'd like to customize my json-server default error handling.

For example, if I do a POST and data already exists, I get a 500 error with this message:

```
Error: Insert failed, duplicate id
    at Function.insert (<...>\node_modules\lodash-id\src\index.js:49:18)
    at <...>\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4388:28
    at arrayReduce (<...>\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:683:21)
    at baseWrapperValue (<...>\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:4387:14)
    at LodashWrapper.wrapperValue (<...>\node_modules\lodash\lodash.js:9050:14)
    at create (<...>\node_modules\json-server\lib\server\router\plural.js:235:48)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (<...>\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (<...>\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at next (<...>\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
    at Route.dispatch (<...>\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
```

Instead of that, I'd like to return a 409 conflit.

I tried to overwrite `router.render`, but render is not called is this specific case.

I've also tried to add a global error handler, but it's not called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found is to manually remove the default error handler.
https://github.com/typicode/json-server/blob/5c0331d1dc0caf72b81c211ca089b5e78a1c8826/src/server/router/index.js#L86

Then, adding a new error handler works:

```
router.stack = router.stack.filter(item => item.handle.length !== 4)

router.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  let status = 500;
  if (err.message === 'Insert failed, duplicate id') {
    status = 409
  }

  res.status(status).send({
    message: err.message
  })
})
```